# How to plot all the latitudes and longitudes on google map using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

```
foreach ($arrResults['statuses'] as $arrSearchResult)
{  
   $geocode  =   file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?         address='.str_replace(" ","+", urlencode($address)).'&sensor=false');
   $output     = json_decode($geocode); 

if($output->status == 'OK')
{ 
    echo "Latitude : ".$latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; 
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Longitude : ".$longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; 
}
```

**and my script is:**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
     var latitude = parseFloat ("<?php echo $latitude; ?>"); 
     var longitude = parseFloat ("<?php echo $longitude; ?>"); 
     var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng (latitude, longitude);

    // Set up options for the Google map
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlngPos,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        }
    };

    // Define the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    // Add the marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlngPos,
        map: map,
        title: "Your Location"
    });

});
</script>
```

as this script is showing only last value of longitude and latitude,but i want to display all the previous locations also.... when i use echo it displays all the latitudes and longitudes.....pls help me

Comment: can somebody help me?????

Comment: is your script gmap script is in php loop? As i understand, i think you want to display the markers[ through lat, lng ] on the map? Please make me correct.

Comment: yes i want to display locations through latitude and longitudes,i have tried to put script inside loop but no result shown

Comment: First collect all the Lat,Lng into an array, then convert array into json object. Pass that object to javascript variable. Then loop through json object to marker section only `var marker = new google.maps.Marker` and pass the lat,lng to the `position: latlngPos` parameter. Hope this make senese.